# Android : Getting server end point to which app is making API calls. (Network / API call tracking)

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I am creating an app which tracks the network details of the user's device.

Trying to build something very much similar to [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor&hl=en)

I searched a lot, but did not get the answer, how can I get the endpoint of the server (ip address of the server) to which app is talking. It would be great if I get other data as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I figured that out somewhat. Every HTTP communication happens through a socket. So I tried to build something around it. Then I found there is SocketImplFactory which you need to implement. And call its createSocket(). So whenever a HTTP (not HTTPS, HTTPS works little different. Have to take care of handshakes and all) call is made a Socket is created. Which in turn calls createSocketImpl() method of SocketImplFactory() which you just have implemented.

Now, in createSocketImpl() method we have to return object of SocketImpl class. And getInputstream() , getOutputstream() methods will be called internally.